# How do I see exactly what characters are in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Check out the weird behavior I'm getting with two strings. I suspect of course, that the space isn't really a space. How do I investigate this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
1.9.2p290> "foo bar".bytes.to_a # the space is a nonbreaking-space
 => [102, 111, 111, 194, 160, 98, 97, 114]
```

or if hex codes for characters are your thing:

```
1.9.2p290> "foo bar".chars.map { |c| c.unpack "H*" } # same nonbreaking-space
 => [["66"], ["6f"], ["6f"], ["c2a0"], ["62"], ["61"], ["72"]]
```

Comment: That worked (1.9.3) and that was exactly the issue as well. I didn't realize there was a such thing as nbsp outside of html, and that #split honors it.

Comment: *Every* HTML entity is just an ASCII representation of some Unicode character, there are no "magic" characters that only exist in HTML